# How to remove rows with empty values on R

Tags: r

My data frame is called `stats`:

```
date          timestamp   filesize        filename          time
2016-03-25    11:44:17    character(0)    s_2_2203_a.jpg    230ms
2016-03-25    11:44:18    21.7Kb          s_2_2208_t.jpg    21.7Kb
2016-03-25    11:44:18    21.9Kb          s_2_2205_a.jpg    21.9Kb
```

I would like to remove the rows where `FileSize` is `character(0)`

This is what I have done so far but didn't work:

```
statsTemp2 = stats[ ! identical(stats$time,character(0)), ]
statsTemp2 = stats[ length(stats$time) > 0L, ]
```

How can I have my data frame looking like this?

```
date          timestamp   filesize        filename          time
2016-03-25    11:44:18    21.7Kb          s_2_2208_t.jpg    21.7Kb
2016-03-25    11:44:18    21.9Kb          s_2_2205_a.jpg    21.9Kb
```

Comment: `stats[!stats$filesize=="character(0)",]` ?

Comment: Do you have a `list `column as "filesize" or `vector`?  Please show the `str(stats)`.  If it is a `list`, `lengths(stats$filesize)!=0`

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(stats)` or the `dput` output for a representative subset in your question. Why do you have `character(0)` in your data.frame column? `NA` or empty string values would be more common,

Comment: easiest `na.omit(stats)`

Comment: @Roland the output of running the dput is massive, I am basically importing the data from a tsv file using 'read.csv(file=x, header=FALSE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like
`newDf <- oldDf [-oldDf$fieldName=='character(0)',]`